# Implementation after class method definition

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

This isn't the exact case, but it is so similar that it completely applies to my situation:

I have a class

```
template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
class MahClass{
    public:
        template<std::size_t S = Size, typename = typename std::enable_if<...>::type>
        operator other_class<T, 1, Size>();
};

// Of course the `...` is substituted for my condition
```

and I would like to implement that conversion operator outside of the class but I have no idea of the required syntax for this.

I have tried:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
MahClass::operator<> other_class<T, 1, Size>(){...}
```

But I know this isn't correct,
what is?

Comment: Tempted to -1 for "Yolo."

Comment: Hang on, let me just change that for you ;)

Comment: +1 for being receptive to peer-pressure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be written in the following manner:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
template <std::size_t S, typename> // <--
MahClass<T, Size>::operator other_class<T, 1, Size>()
//      ^^^^^^^^^
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I actually had that at one point, and now it is complaining about incomplete types :/ I suppose now it's just my own error

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Is it related to the `other_class` class?

Comment: Nope, it's the first class weirdly :L I'm implementing it in a translation unit where it and `other_class` are both defined

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is declare the class and method template argument list.  The class's first, then the method's.  Like this:

```
template<typename T, size_t Size>
template<std::size_t S, typename>
Yolo<T, Size>::operator other_class<T, 1, Size>() { }
```